# unable to send mail from server usiong php mail in html format

Tags: php, linux

i am trying to send mail using php mail function it works good with below code:

```
<?php
$to = "abhwebdesign@gmail.com";
$subject = "subject";
$password="xxxxx";
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body >
<div style='width:670px;height:450px;padding:50px;background-color:#EFEFEB;'>
<div style='width:600px;height:450px;background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#105b94;font-size:20px;padding:10px'>
<img src='http://www.example.com/Images/Index/Logo.png' />
<p>Hi,</p>
<table style='color:#105b94;font-size:20px;'>
<tr>
<td><p>Thank you for registering with us.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br>Your password is :$password<br><br>We appreciate your interest.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><hr>Contact Us <br>Office :9999999999<br>www.example.com
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: Support <support@example.com>' . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

the code works good if i remove www.example.com from above code in the line "**Office :9999999999
www.example.com**" please help me.

Comment: what error does it throw if you do not remote www.example.com

Comment: The code working fine for me, can you please check you mail server configuration

Comment: So, you're trying to send an e-mail live from a (possibly fake) e-mail `example.com`? did you tried with a real one? This information is crucial for all email services.

Comment: i am using a registered mail on hostinger free account.

Comment: Why isn't my solution appropriate for you? Setting HTML Headers on yourself and configure HTML Mails inkl. optional Textversion can be very difficult. I keep strongly recommending you swiftmailer. Kind regards!

Comment: thnks. for the  help.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use: http://swiftmailer.org/

This includes mail headers and configurations. It manages all that stuff you don't want to see.

Kind regards!

Comment: This is really a good suggestion. Who voted that down? Doing HTML mail yourself can be difficult, especially if you want to include a non-HTML version, attachments, and you care about supporting more mail clients than just your own. One vote up from me.

Comment: Thanks for this honesty. Either a lazy user who doesn't want to spend time in a good solution (wink) or another idealistic user who thinks, that doing all the stuff themselves and reinventing the wheel for x times is the only solution :-P